# Enable/Disable the Toolbar of the ListView in a WebPart in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jslink, client-side-rendering, toolbar

I want my listview to have the toolbar as shown in the below pic. This list view is bound to a Document Library. I am new to SharePoint and have no idea how to enable or disable it when needed.

Currently
[image]

Expected
[image]

When opening the WebPart in Edit Mode I see only the below settings and no option to enable to disable the toolbar.

[image]

Below is the code for the web part in the form:-

```
    <OfficeServer:DocumentSetContentsWebPart runat="server" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx}" >
    <WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
      <Title>Download individual item</Title>
      <FrameType>Standard</FrameType>
      <Description>Displays the contents of the Document Set.</Description>
      <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
      <ZoneID>WebPartZone_Top</ZoneID>
      <PartOrder>6</PartOrder>
      <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
      <Height />
      <Width />
      <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
      <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
      <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
      <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
      <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
      <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
      <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
      <DetailLink />
      <HelpLink />
      <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
      <Dir>Default</Dir>
      <PartImageSmall />
      <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
      <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/msimagel.gif</PartImageLarge>
      <IsIncludedFilter />
      <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
      <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
      <ID>xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx</ID>
      <DisplayText>
      </DisplayText>
      <IsAvailable>true</IsAvailable>
    </WebPart></OfficeServer:DocumentSetContentsWebPart>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you edit the page, then edit the web part for that list view, it should open a properties pane for the web part. Do you see an option in the properties pane to change the Toolbar Type?

Comment: No, I don't see any property to change the toolbar type.

Comment: @Thriggle, I found this link which says there are ListViews setting in the web-part for adding the toolbar but I couldn't see them on my site. Do you have any idea how to enable the ListViews setting https://platinumdogs.me/2014/07/16/the-sharepoint-2013-list-view-web-part-toolbar/

Comment: That is strange! I wonder if it is not a list view web part. If you create a new page and add a list web part to the page, does it have the List View properties?

Comment: Thanks, @Thriggle,  you made me realize it was not a listview but a DocumentSet Content .

Answer (score 1):

I had a custom view configured for my Document Set. For me to get this to work, I had to go to the Document Library(Site content -> Document Sets folder (document library name))  and switch to the view (DS view in my case) that was used inside the custom page (even though I was still viewing the whole library).

After switching to that DS view and editing the ViewSetting for Toolbar, the toolbar change showed up on the custom page as well.

Below are the two links which helped me solve the problem.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4b09dd6b-a497-4ca7-88c7-b8164b27c3b0/document-set-toolbar-type?forum=sharepointgeneral

https://platinumdogs.me/2014/07/16/the-sharepoint-2013-list-view-web-part-toolbar/

[image: Highliged are the view on my site]